# Generate ivy.xml with Gradle ivy-publish plugin

Tags: gradle, ivy

Hi I want to make empty project (without source), which to use my jar **helloWorldPlugin** and to manipulate with the ivy descriptor so I made build.gradle in an empty project dir with content:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'ivy-publish'

publishing {
   publications {
     myPublication(IvyPublication) {

     from components.java
   }
repositories {
   ivy {
       url "$project.rootDir/build/publish"
   }
  }
}
```

When I execute

```
gradle publishmyPublicationPublicationToIvyRepository
```

I get xml descriptor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0">
  <info organisation="org.moo" module="ivypublish" revision="9.0-m1-SNAPSHOT" status="integration" publication="20130710180056"/>
  <configurations>
    <conf name="default" visibility="public" extends="runtime"/>
    <conf name="runtime" visibility="public"/>
  </configurations>
  <publications>
    <artifact name="ivypublish" type="jar" ext="jar" conf="runtime"/>
  </publications>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency org="org.moo" name="helloWorldPlugin" rev="9.2-m1-SNAPSHOT" conf="runtime-&gt;default" revConstraint="latest.milestone"/>
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

1.But I don't have all java plugins configurations like test, compile etc.  why?

2.If I don't write **from components.java** in the xml file there is only  tag and other tags like ***dependencies, conf*** are empty. WHy?

3.How to make Gradle to write all java plugin configurations in the ivy descriptor?

Answer (score 1):

A little late here but I believe this may be missing a configurations section in the myPublication. e.g.

```
configurations {
    unitTests { extend 'runtime' }
}
```

and then an associated artifact and task definition for the unit test configuration